# How to notify all persistent actors of particular type

Tags: akka

How to notify all persistent actors of particular type? I have read about Distributed Publish Subscribe but it does not account passivated actors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the persistence backend you're using, and whether it supports [Persistence Query](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence-query.html), you can use the persistence ID queries to get a stream of persistence IDs and use those to resolve a persistent actor for every ID.